# Sending messages to variable numbers

Tags: android, message

I want to design an android app to send a message to variable numbers using a pre input string. Anyone can provide the code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site for providing code for complete apps. It is here to help you solve problems you have with your own implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing a fuction that will help you to send message to various number with predefined numbers list

```
public void send_message(String messageToSend){

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:+8801714262873,+8801887014379,+880000000");
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
            it.putExtra("sms_body", messageToSend);
            startActivity(it);
}
```